# Lua implementation of BestSum function using memoization

Tags: dynamic, lua, memoization

I am trying to translate the below javascript "bestSum" memoization function into lua:

```
 const bestSum = (targetSum,numbers,memo ={}) => {
 if(targetSum in memo) return memo[targetSum];
 if(targetSum === 0 ) return [];
 if(targetSum <0)return null;

 let shortestCombination = null;

   for (let num of numbers) {
     const remainder = targetSum - num;
     const remainderCombination = bestSum(remainder,numbers,memo);
       if (remainderCombination !==null) {
         const combination = [...remainderCombination, num];
          if (shortestCombination === null || combination.length < shortestCombination.length) 
           {
              shortestCombination = combination;
           }
       }

    }

  memo [targetSum] = shortestCombination;
  return shortestCombination;
 }
```

sample test cases with correct results:

```
  console.log(bestSum(7,[5,3,4,7])); //[7]
  console.log(bestSum(8,[2,3,5])); //[3,5]
  console.log(bestSum(8,[1,4,5])); //[4,4]
  console.log(bestSum(100,[1,2,5,25])); //[25,25,25,25]
```

I translated the above javascript into lua as the following:

```
  local function BestSum(target_sum,numbers,memo)
    if memo[target_sum] ~= nil then return  memo[target_sum] end
    if target_sum == 0 then  return {} end
    if target_sum < 0 then return nil end
  
    local shortest_combination = nil
  
    for i, num in ipairs (numbers) do
        local remainder = target_sum - num
        local remainder_combination =  BestSum(remainder,numbers, memo) 
        if remainder_combination ~= nil then
                 local combination = remainder_combination
                  table.insert(combination,num )
             if (shortest_combination == nil) or (#combination < #shortest_combination )then          
                    shortest_combination = combination
             end
        end
     end

      memo[target_sum] = shortest_combination;
      return shortest_combination;
  end
```

but don't get the desired results for the two last cases...... instead get incorrect results:

```
   BestSum(8,{1,4,5},{})==>{"4","1","4"}
   BestSum(150,{5,25},{})==>
```

{"25","5","5","5","5","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25","5","25"}

The results are not even correct let alone being "best" case??

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the translation:

```
local combination = remainder_combination
table.insert(combination, num)
```

Tables are pass by reference, so this isn't creating a new table, it's just assigning the variable `combination` to the same table. Modifying `combination` is just adding more data to `remainder_combination`.

The JavaScript version is taking care to create a new array, and fills it with the contents of the `remainderCombination` array (using '...', the spread operator):

```
const combination = [...remainderCombination, num];
```

This is the most accurate Lua translation:

```
local combination = {unpack(remainder_combination)}
table.insert(combination, num)
```

(Edit: For Lua 5.2+ it's `table.unpack`)

Comment: Awesome, It works... Much appreciated, and my understanding of Lua is a little further ahead!